# How to link to the home URL in a subdirectory when the base href is set to that subdirectory?

Tags: html, url, radix

Here an example of my base URL

```
<base href="http://subdomain.example.com/folder/" />
```

I would like to know how to call that base URL for the HOME link when I try

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

It goes to `http://subdomain.example.com/` and does not include `/folder/`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you need is the virtual directory name of your application/website. 
This is a server variable, and it is not possible to get it in HTML alone, you need some server side component, like PHP or ASP.NET.

If you are in the root directory, you can try a relative link. 
So try using a . to indicate "from this folder"

```
<a href="./">Home</a>
```

Should your question actually concern the opposite direction, do this:

```
<a href="../">Home</a>
```

Or use an absolute link:

```
<a href="/folder">Home</a>
```

Or use a canonical link

```
<a href="http://subdomain.domain.com/folder">Home</a>
```

By the way, you could also set a protocol-relative-link:

```
<a href="//subdomain.domain.com/folder">Home</a>
```

Or if you know where exactly you are right at the moment of the http-request relative to the root, you can infer the root directory link in JavaScript:
e.g. assuming you have "index.htm" in the root-directory, then from a javascript in index.htm, you can get the virtual directory name like this:

```
document.location.pathname.substr(0, document.location.pathname.length-"index.htm".length)
```

Answer (score 5):

#### [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Bpndb/)

It appears that if you are going to start your url (a url that depends on a base url that is) with a `/`, you need to specify that this is from the current directory level.  Thus your link should be

```
<a href="./">Home</a>
```

Comment: no idea what you mean.  My solution works. And if this was based on my solution, you would have downvoted the other poster too... so this is an [emotional response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093234/base-url-how-to-call-the-home-link/7093294#answer-7093317).

Answer (score 1):

ADLADS (A Day Late - A Dollar Short)
I got here and can't relate to the dialog.
For me, I find that I wanted

```
<a href="/index.html">Home</a>
```

Maybe someone else wants this?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate host name with application path and http/https should give you home URL. code below

```
<a href="https://@Request.Url.Host@Request.ApplicationPath">Home</a>
```

Answer (score -6):

Try not to put anything in your HREF, that is, make an empty HREF.

This works in latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE7, IE8, IE9.

Comment: This is only a temporary fix :P as soon as the poster wants to have a another link that doesn't link to the root directory, he can't just drop the href.  Also, I was sure the href was a required attribute of anchor tags.  The real solution is he needs a . before the /

Comment: @Joseph well, you can use it as a temporary fix. But why wouldn't it work for cases other than the OP has mentioned? Any particular case, that this won't work??

Comment: It'll work for a home page, but it won't work as a fix when the poster can't figure out why `<a href="/about.htm">About</a>` doesn't work.  Simply adding the . is cleaner, guaranteed to be cross browser (because that's the way it's supposed to work), and will work in the future when the poster attempts to add other links.

Comment: I don't down vote flippantly.  I feel this answer can be detrimental to those who come across the same issue.  If I did this based on feelings, I would not have done it in this way.  I have no personal quarrel with you.  I simply think this answer can cause problems rather than pointing out the real issue of what went wrong.