# Linking to index.html with slash takes me to my computer's root directory

Tags: html

I am having a simple but frustrating problem.  I have a logo on my website that I want to link back to the website's homepage.  If i do href="index.html" it works but I when I try to do href="/", which I believe should also work, it takes me to the literal root directory of my computer.

For example, if I have href="/" and then I click on my logo, it directs me here:
[image: my root directory]

Will this be alleviated as soon as it's hosted on a server? Any insight into this behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, an href of "/" is the root of where the file is being served from, in this case your local file system.

However, I do believe that setting an href of "index.html" or "/index.html" would be slightly more optimized performance, as "/" just resolves to "index.html" anyways.

I would also suggest you set up your local environment to have a local server, where the files are served not just read by your browser. MAMP is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a problem that will only occur if you're viewing a site off your filesystem rather than a local or remote server.

If you'd like to prevent this anyway, you could use relative paths rather than absolute. For example:

- If you're on `/photos/index.html` and would like your header logo to go to `/`, your link could be: `../` to go up one directory.
- If you're on `/index.html` and would like your header logo to point to the current directory, your link could be: `./` to stay in the current folder level.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this option to disable directory listing and display contents of index.html

Create a `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Or you can have this option in the `<VirtualHost>` directive.

Answer (score 1):

What you wanted to do can be done by :

```
<a href = "./"></a>
```

[This will clear the differnce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0f3e.png)

Further Refrence

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

https://html.com/attributes/a-href/#Different_URL_Forms

This problem was already answered

[Base URL - How to call the home link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093234/base-url-how-to-call-the-home-link)